# Ignite DROP Index - Cache doesn't exist?

Tags: ignite

When running SELECT queries ignite cache discovery happens with no errors, however when attempting to DROP an existing index getting an exception:

```
class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Cache doesn't exist: <cache_name>
```

The only reference I could find in is in [here](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Index-not-getting-created-td18535.html), with resolution being restarting the caches which is not desired behaviour.

Why is cache not found during DDL statements but found for DML?

Comment: Could you share the queries you use to create the table and create/drop the indexes?

Comment: As well, which version of Ignite do you use?