# Can't create index

Tags: ignite

When running CREATE INDEX SQL I get
`Error: Cache doesn't exist: xxxxx`

SQL used: `CREATE INDEX test ON PUBLIC.REPORTS (START_DATE)`

- Query data on the table works.
- Creating index on other tables works.

I've seen some other people having the same problem but no solution:
[Ignite DROP Index - Cache doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165353/ignite-drop-index-cache-doesnt-exist)

Comment: If this table is different than the others I guess you'd better post the table schema.  It might be worth your time to compare that schema to one of the other tables to see if you notice any important differences.

Comment: They are completely different tables. I had the same table schema and data in another cluster that I wiped out and I could create the indexes there. I believe its something with this cluster.

Comment: The table have 80 columns and one column as PK

Comment: I just created another table with exactly same schema (but no data) and was able to create an index.

Comment: Which version of Ignite do you use? How did you create that table? Could you share a reproducer?

Comment: I'm using ignite 2.7. I created the table using DBeaver (CREATE TABLE). I can't reproduce since it was very circumstantial. After recreating the table it worked. But clearly there is a case where the problem can happen (also another 3 ppl have had the same problem).

Comment: Can you share the configuration of the problematic cache (or the `CREATE TABLE` command)? Also, how do you run SQL? Via JDBC? Can you share the JDBC connection string you use?